# How to set the backgroundcolor with a function in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, components

So basically I have a div and I need to apply 1 of 3 possible colors based on the value, from 0 to 29 the color is red, from 30 to 69 the color is yellow and for 70 to 100 the color is green, what I'm doing right now is creating a function that based on the value applies one style or another using an object, like this:

```
const useStyles = {
  bar: {
    low: {
      backgroundColor: "#f44336"
    },
    ...
  }
}

const handleBackgroundColor = (valueInPercent: Number) => {
    if (valueInPercent < 30) {
        return useStyles.bar.low;
    } else if (valueInPercent >= 30 && valueInPercent <= 70) {
        return useStyles.bar.medium;
    }
    return useStyles.bar.high;
}

<div 
  style={ 
    height: "75px", width: '75px', 
    backgroundColor: handleBackgroundColor(valueInPercent) }}
/>
```

But I get this error:

> Type '{ backgroundColor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'BackgroundColor | undefined'.

Does someone knows how to fix this or is there a way to use a ternary operator for this?

I solved it removing the object notation, and leave it like this:

```
bar: {
    low: "#f44336",
    medium: "#efbb5aa3",
    high: "#088208a3"
}
```

Comment: `useStyles.bar.medium` and `useStyles.bar.high` are `undefined`

Comment: I solved it, just needed to remove the object notation and leave it like this: 

const useStyles = {
  bar: {
    low: "#f44336"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the declaration of `bar` to this:

```
bar: {
    low: "#f44336",
    medium: "#efbb5aa3",
    high: "#088208a3"
}
```